# Lambda to send SNS notification

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an S3 Bucket - where when an object (csv gets loaded) - lambda get triggered. Lambda then takes this csv and upload into Dynamo DB. Now after Dynam DB is updated - i need to  send SNS notification.

Below is my code. below code inserts into Dynamo DB - however it doesnot come out of the Loop to execute SNS portion.
If i comment out - for loop (put_item) the SNS works and i am able to get the Notification.

```
import os
import boto3
import json
import logging

log_level = os.environ['LOG_LEVEL']
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(log_level)

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Fetch the bucket name and the file
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    log.info("Event: " + (str(event)))

    # Generate record in DynamoDB
    try :
        # Declare S3 bucket and DynamoDB Boto3 Clients
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

        # Read the Object using get_object API
        obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        rows = obj['Body'].read().decode("utf-8").split('\n')

        tableName = os.environ['DB_TABLE_NAME']
        table = dynamodb.Table(tableName)

        log.info("TableName: " + tableName)


        try :
            # Write the CSV file to the DynamoDB Table
            with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for row in rows:       
                    batch.put_item(Item={
                        'A': row.split(',')[0],
                        'B': row.split(',')[1],
                        'C': row.split(',')[2],
                        'D': row.split(',')[3]
                        })


            print('Finished Inserting into TableName: ' + tableName)
        except dynamodb_client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException as tableNotFoundEx:
            return ('ERROR: Unable to locate DynamoDB table: ', tableName)


    except KeyError as dynamoDBKeyError:
        msg = 'ERROR: Need DynamoDB Environment Var: DB_TABLE_NAME'
        print(dynamoDBKeyError)
        return msg;

    log.info("Finished Inserting into TableName: " + tableName)

    # Send Notificaiton to SNS
    try :
        topicName = os.environ['SNS_TOPIC_ARN']
        print('*SNS TopicName*=', topicName)
        log.info("TopicName: " +  topicName)

        sns_client = boto3.client('sns')

        sns_client.publish(
            TopicArn = topicName,
            Message = "Vehicle Master data updated in DynamoDB!"
        )

        print('Generated new SNS message, ID: ' + recordId)
        log.info("Generated new SNS message, Topic: " + topicName)

    except KeyError as snsKeyError:
        msg = 'ERROR: Need SNS Environment Var: SNS_TOPIC_NAME'
        print(snsKeyError)
        return msg;

    # return
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps('Updated to DDB!')
    }
```

I am not sure -where the error is:

Comment: Not sure why the loop is failing termination, but have you looked into DynamoDB streams which can publish the data into SNS directly. This way you don't have to publish the success message in SNS topic explicitly.

Comment: do you have any exception thrown? in current implementation you sns message will be published only in case of successful insertion of records

Comment: I agree with @GiorgosDev, it is quite possible that you may be getting Throttling exception while batch writing the items in your DynamoDB table if the WCUs of your table are not rightly configured as per the TPS.

Comment: No exception thrown - insert is happening to Dynamo DB - However it seems it doesnt come out of the loop.

Comment: can you print rows size, may be your document has huge number of rows and times out before processing all of them?

Comment: 55k records - 5sec in lambda is configured

Comment: lambda Task is timed out even if i set 5 min.